# EBS Snapshots: how data works with incremental backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

If I have snapshots S1, S2, S3 which are taken while data varying in EBS. S1 is oldest snapshot and S3 is latest snapshot. If I delete the S1, does S3 has all the latest data which was there by the time of taking S3 snapshot on EBS?

Comment: When you delete a snapshot, only the data exclusive to that snapshot is removed. Deleting previous
snapshots of a volume do not affect your ability to restore volumes from later snapshots of that volume

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a snapshot, only the data exclusive to that snapshot is removed. Deleting previous snapshots of a volume do not affect your ability to restore volumes from later snapshots of that volume.

If you make periodic snapshots of a volume, the snapshots are incremental so that only the blocks on the device that have changed since your last snapshot are saved in the new snapshot. Even though snapshots are saved incrementally, the snapshot deletion process is designed so that you need to retain only the most recent snapshot in order to restore the volume.

```
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-deleting-snapshot.html
```